# Google Hangout Client - video not available

Tags: 12.10, google-talk

I am new to ubuntu. The problem is that no video is available though mic works fine . If I try the simple video chat in Gmail that works but not in Google Hangout. I know it is a duplicate of similar question but when I look at the answers for that duplicate Q there I am not sure which command to apply in my case. Maybe it is different than the answers in that case.
[My webcam is not working with Google+ Hangout, can I make it work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51394/my-webcam-is-not-working-with-google-hangout-can-i-make-it-work)

Comment: Mind adding the duplicate Q&A you're referring to here? (either in your question or as a comment) That way we might be able to help you better.